# How to embed an executable plugin in my website?

Tags: java, jsp, plugins, mac-address

I want to embed an executable plugin in my website that will return client's Mac address run time. I am working with jsp/servlet. Please Help.

Comment: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(parent, "Wots U MAC addy?")` is a correct but sarcastic answer, that will hopefully prompt you to explain what the use of this (nonsense) is.

Answer (score 0):

You could have used a Java signed applet then embed applet code on to your jsp.

```
<applet code="/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/SignedAppletDemo.class"
    archive="SSignedApplet.jar"
    width=400 height=400>
    <param name=file value="/etc/inet/hosts">
</applet>
```

see [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) for the complete reference.